# Why is this shorthand if statement returning 0 when the long form works?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I have the following code where I have a value that is defined, but when I try to do any shorthand equation on it, it returns 0.

### Ternary operation

```
$m = 1.10;
echo 'Markup Percentage : ' . ( $m > 1 ? ($m * 100) - 100 :  'N/A' ) + ' %';
```

Result:

> Markup Percentage : 0 %

---

### Standard operation.

```
$m = 1.10;

echo 'Markup Percentage : ';    
if($m > 1) {
   echo ($m * 100) - 100;
} else {
   echo 'N/A';
}
echo ' %';
```

> Markup Percentage : 10 %

---

In case it isn't obvious, the result of the Ternary operation should be the same as the standard operation. What am I doing wrong or is this a bug in php 5.4 ?

Comment: is this a typo ? `+ ' %'`

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: It always helps to _talk to the wall_—read it out loud for your cat or something :)

Comment: @Michael - perhaps my cat should be coding for me late at night.  Been around long enough I think it's reasonable to assume she should have picked up a few skills by now ^^

Comment: @SanuelJackson haha, well why don't you try for a week or two, while you go do cat stuff :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because of wrong operator. `.` is used for concatenation, not `+`. Try with -

```
$m = 1.10;
echo 'Markup Percentage : ' . ( ($m > 1) ? (($m * 100) - 100) :  'N/A' ) . ' %';
```

But I would suggest to group the operations properly when using ternary operators. Not only for ternary, for all operators. Understanding the precedence is very important.

```
echo 'Markup Percentage : ' . ( $m > 1 ? ($m * 100) - 100 :  'N/A' ) . ' %';
```

Should also work.

Comment: excellent to both you and Kausha.  getting late again, i didn't even notice '+' instead of '.' lol.   also encapsulating in extra brackets around conditions was the first thing i tried, but that  '+' was killing it.

Answer (score 1):

This is, happening because you are using multiple calculation without `(`, so they messed up, and another mistake is you are using `+` sign in place of `.`.

You can use ternary operator like below:

```
$m = 1.10;
echo 'Markup Percentage : ' . ( ($m > 1) ? (($m * 100) - 100) : 'N/A' ) . ' %';
//OP: Markup Percentage : 10 %
```